# In Salesforce Wave, How do we show a chart with data grouped by Year, Quarter, Month, Week using a Toggle Widget?

Tags: salesforce1-app, analytics, einstein-analytics, widget

**In Salesforce Wave**, How do we show a chart with data grouped by Year, Quarter, Month, Week using a Toggle Widget?

I would need to group a Trending chart with this filter type toggle widget.

Kindly advise.  Thanks